# How can I make a frequency plot of successful trials?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, import, histograms

I have got different files with the result of an experiment varying 2 variables. The files are in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xg2epnxxpwqyrl8/AADSYg90bY4m6d3MjESLC1Eca?dl=0). Each file has 3 columns of data: the first column is the same for all the rows of the file but changes from file to file and represents the first variable; a second column is a float number and represents the second variable. The third column in each file represents the success with 1 and, the failure of the experiment with a 0.

I would like to get the frequency of successes in XY bins. For example, if {X,0.1,0.7} and {Y,0,30}, divide this region like it does the function `FindDivisions[]` and count the successes found in this division and divide this number by the total number of points in this division.

With these generated data points, I would like to plot the result with stems or with a surface. Also, I would like to compute an interpolation function with them to get the success probability passing any XY values to the function.

Comment: There's no indication that these questions are related to the software package *Mathematica*.  Was there something unclear about the *Mathematica* documentation on `Import` and `Plot3D`?

Comment: I find the sentence "I would like to ask how to make bins the points and substitute them by a center XY datapoint and with a Z value equivalent to the probability of success (number_of_1's/ number_of_(0's+1's))." totally unclear. I believe it to be the critical sentence of your post. Should the others reading your post find it unclear as well, you will not get an answer and your question will be closed..

Comment: @m_goldberg You are right. The sentence is unclear. I have changed it. I hope now will be clearer. I am sorry.

Comment: @JimB I just wanted some indication of how to proceed and solve the problem.

Comment: It sounds like an appropriate model might be a logistic regression which can be found using `GeneralizedLinearModelFit` or `LogitModelFit`.  A related type of model would be `ProbitModelFit`.  That would give you a predictive model rather than just a data display (although a display is essential, too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an extended comment.  It's many times a good idea to get a plot of the raw data.

```
data = Flatten[Import["*.txt", "Data"], 1];

(* Jitter the first variable by a little bit *)
data2 = data;
data2[[All, 1]] = data2[[All, 1]] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.0015], Length[data]];

(* Separate the data in the 0's and 1's *)
data0 = Select[data2, #[[3]] == 0 &][[All, {1, 2}]];
data1 = Select[data2, #[[3]] == 1 &][[All, {1, 2}]];

(* Plot the data clouds *)
ListPlot[data0, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.8}, {-5, 35}}, ImageSize -> Large,
 PlotLabel -> Style["0", 18, Bold], PlotStyle -> Red]
ListPlot[data1, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.8}, {-5, 35}}, ImageSize -> Large,
 PlotLabel -> Style["1", 18, Bold], PlotStyle -> Green]
ListPlot[{data0, data1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.8}, {-5, 35}}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotLabel -> Style["Both 0 and 1", 18, Bold], 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image: data with zeros]

[image: data with ones]

[image: data with zeros and ones]

***Addition:***  Maybe it's easier than I thought to get the proportion estimates:

```
(* Set some bins *)
bins = {{9/100, 71/100, 2/100}, {-5, 33, 2}};

(* Total number of observations in each bin *)
n = HistogramList[data[[All, {1, 2}]], bins];
(* Number of ones in each bin *);
ones = HistogramList[Select[data, #[[3]] == 1 &][[All, {1, 2}]], bins];

(* Generate a table of triplets with bin centers and proportion of ones *)
{d1, d2} = Dimensions[n[[2]]]
proportions = 
  Flatten[Table[{(n[[1, 1, i - 1]] + n[[1, 1, i]])/2, (n[[1, 2, j - 1]] + n[[1, 2, j]])/2,
     If[n[[2, i, j]] == 0, -1, ones[[2, i, j]]/n[[2, i, j]]]}, {i, 2, d1}, {j, 2, d2}], 1];
proportions = Select[proportions, #[[3]] >= 0 &];

(* Show results *)
ListPointPlot3D[proportions]
```

[image: 3D plot of proportions]

Comment: I wanted to thank you for the solution. I have tested each step of the solution, and it is what I needed. It requires practice to know how to visualize the data introducing the jitter :-). I would also ask you how to select the correct bins, and if it is a way to select the bins if the values of the data change. Thank you.

Comment: The jittering was just to give folks an idea as to where all of the data was (since it was very systematically collected and it would be harder to assess with just looking at the raw data values).  There is no "correct" bin size or orientation.  Because what you almost certainly need is to create a predictive equation the bin size is irrelevant for that but definitely good for looking at the goodness-of-fit for the model being fitted to the data.

Comment: You are right. I need to find a function to interpolate XY points. I have tried `Interpolation[]` of `proportions`, but since the function is not defined with data points in the part without bins, the interpolated function gives Z values that are incorrect. I have made some tests and posted a new question in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193972/how-to-remove-unnecessary-filling-in-listplot3d